# Permutation of α ∈ S9

Tags: permutations

Let $α ∈ S_9$ be the permutation given by
$$α(1) = 6;α(2) = 8;α(3) = 7;α(4) = 9;$$
$$α(5) = 3;α(6) = 4;α(7) = 5;α(8) = 2;α(9) = 1.$$
Decompose the permutations α first as a product of disjoint cycles and
then as a product of transpositions. Find $α^{−1}$ and $α^2$
. What are the order
and sign of α? Find $α^{122}$
.

I have found that $a=(1 6 4 9),(2 8),(3 7 5)$ and $o(a)=LCM(4,2,3)=12$.

The sign of $a=(=1)*(-1)*(1)=1$

$a=(1 9)(1 4)(1 6) (2 8)(3 5)(3 7)$

$a^{-1}=(1 9 4 6)(2 8)(3 5 7)$
and $a^2=$ $(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 / 4 2 5 1 7 9 3 8 6)$
so, $a^2$ is $(1 4)(3 5 7)(6 9)$

How can I find $a^{122}$?

Comment: note since the order of $a$ is 12, $a^{12}=e$.  How does $122$ relate to $12$? by division?

Comment: can you explain it more because I didnt understand it? at the beginning I tried to do a^2*a^2=a^4 then a^4*a^4=a^8 but I dont know if I can do this

Comment: $122=12\cdot 10+2$.  So $a^{122}=a^{12\cdot 10+2}=$...

Comment: so I have to find the mod? I got a little bit confuse

Answer (score 1):

In any  group, if the order of an element $g$ is $n$, we have
$$ g^N=g^{N\bmod n}. $$

This is very often at work when calculating a huge power  of a number modulo a prime $p\,$: it suffices to apply *Fermat's theorem* to know the order of the (non divisible by $p$) number, which asserts the order of the number mod. $p$ is a divisor of $p-1$, hence $$x^N\equiv x^{N\bmod p-1}\mod p.$$

Comment: why do I have to use Fermat's theorem? I think i don't need to find mod because it ask me to find a^122. I have found a^2. Can I use the a^2 as a hint to find the answer? As, they say to me before 122=a^(12*12+2) but how can I use this to find the answer?

Comment: Fermat's theorem was just an example to show this is a common problem. Since  $122\equiv 2\bmod 12$, and the order of $a$ is $12$, it should be clear that $a^{122}=a^2$.

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much I didnt think about it